# jQuery break an each loop on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery each loop with an ajax function inside but I'm experiencing an issue when trying to navigate away from this page while the loop is still running, basically I can't navigate to any other page unless the each loop has finished.

I don't need this loop to finish because it's basically only needed as a visual indicator, its far from being so important to sacrifice user experience for.

```
    $.each( get_link, function( i, val ) {

    $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        return false;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: true,
        data: {url: val},
        success: function(data)
        {
            let row = $("#status[data-url='" + val + "']");
            row.html(data);
            $("#loader[data-url='" + val + "']").removeClass("loader vertical-align-middle loader-bounce");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I have tried to fix it with `$(window).on("beforeunload")` but `beforeunload` creates an unnecessary alert window which unfortunately I couldn't find a way to disable.

**EDIT:** The above code isn't breaking the loop either...

Is `beforeunload` a good idea? Maybe there are better approaches to break a loop on page exit?

f.khantsis suggested to abort the ajax operation which is a good idea but it doesn't help because I run an each loop on an array with 5-6 keys. So if one of them is aborted the loop just goes on to run with all the remaining keys.

Comment: your beforeunload doesn't do anything, since it just returns false from the listener.

Comment: The thing is, it works. As soon as the alert appears everything else is not loading anymore as if the loop was stopped. Edit: You are right, it stops the loop until I confirm. Then I wait till the loop finishes :(

Answer (score 0):

see [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Basically, `jQuery.ajax` returns a [jqXHR](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object, which can be used to abort a pending request.

```
$.each( get_link, function( i, val ) {

    var xhr = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      async: true,
      data: {url: val},
      success: function(data)
      {
          let row = $("#status[data-url='" + val + "']");
          row.html(data);
          $("#loader[data-url='" + val + "']").removeClass("loader vertical-align-middle loader-bounce");
      }
    });
    $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
      xhr.abort();
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like the ajax is non-functional when I navigate to another page, but I still have to wait quite some time before the actual redirect.

Comment: when you `.abort()`, it should solve the lag problem

Comment: Well, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).on("beforeunload")` should probably be outside your loop.

Then it can set a global variable which you would then check for in your loop, something like:

```
var leavingThePage = false;

$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        leavingThePage = true;
});

$.each( get_link, function( i, val ) {
    if (leavingThePage)
        return false;

    $.ajax({
      ... Do ajax stuff ...
    });
});
```